# Autosys job to run every minute except on certain days

Tags: autosys

I'm looking for a way to run an autosys job every minute of the day except Sunday between 11:00 and  12:00.  Is there a way to accomplish this without creating 3 jobs (one that runs Mon-Sat, one that runs Sunday until 11am, and one that runs Sunday after 12)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two jobs. One that runs from Monday-Saturday and one that runs on Sunday in which you can specify the run_window from 12:00-11:00.